# Dexguard removing AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, proguard, dexguard

After an upgrade to Dexguard 8.3 (from 8.1), with no change to Proguard/Dexguard definitions, we have started seeing the AndroidManifest being stripped away from the resulting APK, causing the following error when attempting to install:

```
adb: failed to install app-release.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: Failed to parse /data/app/vmdl173476881.tmp/base.apk: AndroidManifest.xml]
```

Our definitions are:

```
proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro')
proguardFile 'dexguard-prod.pro' (our own custom)
proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro' (our own custom)
```

And I have attempted to add the following to our own dexguard-prod.pro file (As per Dexguard's own documentation, the default configuration should contain this) without it helping:

```
-keepresourcefiles AndroidManifest.xml
```

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Turns out that Dexguard 8.3 does not fully support Gradle 3.3.0. After a downgrade to 3.2.1 the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Dexguard 8.3 does not fully support Gradle 3.3.0. After a downgrade to 3.2.1 the problem was solved.

Comment: Support for Android gradle plugin 3.3.0 was added in DexGuard 8.4.